# Using a list of dataframes as lookups for new columns in other dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of some 500.000 trees in different sites, and am trying to find out which sites are more endangered by specific pests (n ~500). Each pest has a different host range. I have these host ranges in dataframes in a list.
I am trying to use these dfs in the list as lookup tables, and will calculate fraction of suitable trees.

Example code:

```
#pests with their host ranges
pest1 <- as.data.frame(c("Abies", "Quercus"))
pest2 <- as.data.frame(c("Abies"))
pest3 <- as.data.frame (c("Abies", "Picea"))
pestlist <- as.list(c(pest1, pest2, pest3))
#changing this to any other kind of list would be fine too


df1 <- NULL#this will be the dataframe that would get new columns
df1$genus <- c("Abies", "Picea", "Abies", "Quercus", "Abies")
df1$site <- c("A" , "A" , "B" , "B", "B")
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```

I tried following code, but it seems to go wrong because I don't know how to loop through lists:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- map2(pestlist, names(df1), mutate(ifelse(df1$genus %in% pestlist , 1,0)))
```

For clarity, I want to go from:

[image: df1]

to

[image: df2]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix up your `pestlist` like this:

```
pestlist =do.call(
  rbind,lapply(seq_along(pestlist),\(i) data.frame(pest=i,genus=pestlist[[i]]))
)
```

then you can join `df1` and a version of `pestlist` that has been pivoted to wide format

```
inner_join(
  df1, pivot_wider(
    mutate(pestlist,v=1),
    names_from=pest,names_prefix = "pest",values_from = v,values_fill = 0
  )
)
```

Output:

```
    genus site pest1 pest2 pest3
1   Abies    A     1     1     1
2   Picea    A     0     0     1
3   Abies    B     1     1     1
4 Quercus    B     1     0     0
5   Abies    B     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a named list of vectors instead of a list of data.frames. Then we can use `map_dfc()` inside `mutate()`:

```r
# use vectors instead of data.frames
pest1 <- c("Abies", "Quercus")
pest2 <- c("Abies")
pest3 <- c("Abies", "Picea")


df1 <- NULL#this will be the dataframe that would get new columns
df1$genus <- c("Abies", "Picea", "Abies", "Quercus", "Abies")
df1$site <- c("A" , "A" , "B" , "B", "B")
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

library(tidyverse)

# create named list of vectors
pestlist <- tibble::lst(pest1, pest2, pest3)

# use map_dfc
df1 %>%
  mutate(map_dfc(pestlist, ~ as.integer(genus %in% .x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = 'genus')

pestdt = rbindlist(list(pest1, pest2, pest3), use.names = FALSE, idcol = TRUE)
setnames(pestdt, c('id', 'genus'))
pestdt = dcast(pestdt, genus ~ paste0('pest', id), value.var = 'genus', fun.aggregate = \(x) as.integer(nzchar(x)), fill = 0)
cols   = paste0("pest", 1:3)

df1[, (cols) := pestdt[.SD, mget(cols)]]
# 
#      genus   site pest1 pest2 pest3
#     <char> <char> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:   Abies      A     1     1     1
# 2:   Abies      B     1     1     1
# 3:   Abies      B     1     1     1
# 4:   Picea      A     0     0     1
# 5: Quercus      B     1     0     0
```